# Django обновление изображения

Tags: python, django

Не получается  обновить картинку через сайт, при этом логин и мыло обновляются, через админку проблем нету. Также при регистрации, не загружается изображение, ставится изображение по дефолту. Нашел решение где вьюшка написана через функцию, работает, но хочется найти проблему в моем коде.

Есть модель:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField('Фото пользователя', default='default_user.png', upload_to='user_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Профайл пользователя {self.user.username}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()

        image = Image.open(self.img.path)

        if image.height > 256 or image.width > 256:
            resize = (256, 256)
            image.thumbnail(resize)
            image.save(self.img.path)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профайл'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профайлы'
```

Форма:

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Введите новый Email',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Введите Email'})
    )
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='Введите новый логин',
        required=False,
        help_text='Нельзя вводить символы: @, /, _',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Введите логин'})
    )
    img = forms.ImageField(
        label='Загрузить новую фотографию',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.FileInput
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'img']
```

Вьюшка:

```
class UserEditProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/edit_profile.html'
    form_class = UserEditForm
    success_url = '/profile/'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.id)
```

Html файл:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-register mt-4">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Обновиться</button>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

[Эта тема](https://djangodoc.ru/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/) помогла разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

могу лишь сказать, что столкнулся с той же проблемой, но у меня попросту не было прописано `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, в вашем же случае я бы попробовал `action=""`.